# Adding two String variables for filter in JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Assume I have an entity with two variables: name and surname. I want to create a JPQL method which will return a list of objects whose ***name + " " + surname*** will match the search. I have tried creating the following JPQL method, but it does not work. I could have created an additional variable inside my entity-class which would sum up the name and surname; but this is bad practise. Many thanks.

```
 public List<User> findUserByFullName(String fullName) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("select c from DefaultUser c where c.name + ' ' + c.surname like :custName").setParameter("custName", fullName)
                        .getResultList();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just split the name in the Java and then query off the split name?

That will then allow the Database to use its indexes properly too.

```
String[] names = fullName.split(" ");

 return entityManager.createQuery("select c from DefaultUser c where c.name = :name and c.surname like :surName").setParameter("name", names[0]).setParameter("surName", names[names.length-1]).getResultList();
```

Comment: Many thanks Tim B. Totally forgot about the .split() method. Still, I did not know that it is possible to assign two parameters for the JPQL result so thank you very much, I have learnt something new today.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `CONCAT` function in your JPQL query to form the full name, like this:

```
select c from DefaultUser c where concat(c.name, ' ', c.surname) like :custName
```

See **Section 4.6.17.2.1 String Functions** in the [Java Persistence 2.0, Final Release](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf) for more details.